# How do I get milliseconds to hours, minutes, secs and remaining millisecs

Tags: java

Ok, so I've recently started programming in java about a week ago, and I'm attempting to write a program that will take milliseconds and give me hours, minutes, seconds, and remaining milliseconds. Now I've got most of it down its just for some reason, giving me numbers that are off. I should be getting 2hrs, 46 min, 40 seconds, and 123 milliseconds. But instead I'm getting 2hrs, 2min, 3secs, and 123 milliseconds.

Heres my code

```
   int beginning = 10000123; //beginning is the starting number of milli seconds
   int hours = beginning/3600000;
   int rSecs = beginning%1000; //r = remaining
   int minutes = rSecs/60;
   int seconds = rSecs%60;
   int milliSecs = rSecs%1000;
   
   System.out.println("Lab03, 100 Point Version\n");
   System.out.println("Starting Milliseconds" + beginning); 
   System.out.println("Hours:" + hours);
   System.out.println("Minutes:" + minutes);
   System.out.println("Seconds:" + seconds);
   System.out.println("Milli Seconds:" +  milliSecs);
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: `beginning%1000` -> `beginning%3600000` then `rSecs/60` -> `rSecs/60000` and so so

Comment: you can use:

        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds()
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes()
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modulo by `3600000` for remaining milli second

```
int hours = beginning/3600000;
int rMiliSecs = beginning%3600000;
```

Since it millisecond you need to divide by 60000(1m-> 60s -> 60000ms) for minute and modulo by 60000 to get remainings

```
int minutes = rMiliSecs/60000;
rMiliSecs = rMiliSecs%60000;
```

Then divide by 1000 for the second and modulo by 1000(1s -> 1000ms) for remaining millisecond

```
int seconds = rMiliSecs/1000;
int milliSecs = rMiliSecs%1000;
```

Comment: Thank so much for clearing that up for me. I did another version of this program where I converted seconds into the hours minutes and remaining secs, and when I changed it to milliseconds I forgot to account for that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the magic numbers and do a more OO approach you can use the Duration class.

```
                Duration duration = Duration.ofMillis(10000123);
                long hours = duration.toHours();
                duration = duration.minusHours(hours);
                long minutes = duration.toMinutes();
                duration = duration.minusMinutes(minutes);
                long seconds = duration.getSeconds();
                duration = duration.minusSeconds(seconds);
                long milliSec = duration.toMillis();
```